# Show that the expected value of the sum of discrete random variable is the sum of the expected values.

Tags: probability

I want to solve the following exercise:

Suppose the possible values of $X$ are $\{x_i\}$, the possible values of $Y$ are $\{y_j\}$, and the possible values of $X+Y$ are $\{z_k\}$. Let $A_k$ denote the following set : $A_k=\{ (i,j)=x_i+y_j=z_k \}$

a) Argue that: $P\{X+Y= z_k\}= \sum _{(i,j)\in A_k}P\{X=x_i,Y=y_j\}$

b) Show that: $E[X+Y]=\sum_k \sum_{(i,j)\in A_k}(x_i+y_j) P\{X=x_i,Y=y_j\}$

c) Using the formula from part (b), Argue that $E[X+Y]= \sum_i \sum_j (x_i+y_j) P\{X=x_i,Y=y_j\}$

d)Show that: $P\{X=x_i\}= \sum_j P\{X=x_i,Y=y_j\}$ , $P\{Y=y_j \}= \sum_i P\{X=x_i,Y=y_j\}$

e) Prove that $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$

I have read these link: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/104 but the thing is that it does not cover the things in the exercise, well we have already prove in class that $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ , but not with these methods, I can't figure out all the steps because I am really in blank on how can I proceed in the above problems. Can you help me to solve this exercise please? :)

Thanks a lot I appreciate your help in advance :).

Comment: Which step are you stuck on? Pretty much all exercises are just application of definitions, and only crucial observation needed here is that sets $A_k$ partition the set $X\times Y$. I really just gave you answer to all questions by saying that, and the rest is obvious applications of definitions.

Comment: well basically the thing is that I don't know how to begin :)

Comment: Okay, so for (a) you could argue like this: if $X+Y=z_k$, then what pairs of values $(x_i,y_j)$ such that when $X=x_i, Y=y_j$ give you $X+Y=z_k$ where does $(i,j)$ belong then?

Comment: well the pair of indices in $A_k$ :) isn't?

Comment: Then $P(X+Y=z_k)=$sum of all probabilities such that $X=x_i, Y=y_j$ which is equal to..?

Comment: Well I don't understand much, because I think you have a typo

Comment: Well I got it is equal to the result we want :) isn't ?, and can I argue like this or how can I write it?

Answer (score 1):

You should always understand what $P(X=k)$ means, because really it is an abuse of notation.

$P(X + Y = z_k)$ should really be written as $P(\{\omega: X(\omega) + Y(\omega) = z_k\})$.
The key observation is that probability is defined on a sigma-algebra so you can only calculate the probability of a set! (all the sets that are in the sigma algebra)

So you will need to write that set in a different manner to get to your result. The idea is to write it as the union of disjoint sets, so that you can apply $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$. 
Well since $\{\omega: X(\omega) + Y(\omega) = z_k\} = \bigcup_{i,j \in A_k} \{\omega: X(\omega) = x_i \ and \ Y(\omega) = y_j\}$ and this sets are disjoint, you have

$$P(X + Y = z_k) = P (\{\omega: X(\omega) + Y(\omega) = z_k\} = P\left(\bigcup_{i,j \in A_k} \{\omega: X(\omega) = x_i \ and \ Y(\omega) = y_j\}\right) =$$$$= \sum_{i,j \in A_k} P(\{\omega: X(\omega) = x_i \ and \ Y(\omega) = y_j\}) = \sum_{i,j \in A_k} P(X = x_i, Y = y_j)$$

The second point is easy: if we have discrete random variables, then $E[X] = \sum x_i P(X = x_i)$. You just need to apply the definition. Similarly for the other points

Comment: Well what is a sigma algebra ?

Comment: @user162343 Oh well is a collection of sets with some properties (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra). It's not essential though to understand it; just remember that you can only assign probabilities to a set, and expressions like $P(X=k)$ are abuse of notation. I stress this point because I believe is a source of confusion

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, If you can complete the proof of the other exercises with basic things in probability I´ll aprecciate it a lot :)

Comment: @user162343 You should try to them yourself! Think long and hard about them and you'll come through :)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help @Ant :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you could write for (a):

\begin{align*}
P(X+Y=z_k)&=\sum P(X=x_i,Y=y_j,x_i+y_j=z_k) = \sum_{(i,j)\in A_k}P(X=x_i,Y=y_j) 
\end{align*}

and this should be more than enough for any mathematicians out there. This pretty much sum up what I've been saying, right?

(b) By definition, you have

$$
E[X+Y]=\sum_{k} z_k P(X+Y=z_k)
$$
and can you rewrite above to get what you are asked to have?

(c) Now comes crucial observation: notice that by definition the sets $A_k$ partition $X\times Y$ (do you see this?)

So the summation

$$
\sum_{k} \sum_{(i,j)\in A_k} = \sum_{\text{all possible (i,j)}}=\sum_j \sum_i
$$

and thats it.

---

edit: $$
\sum_{\text{all possible $(i,j)$}} P(X=x_i,Y=y_j)
$$

is same as first summing over all possible $i$, and then summing over all possible $j$; think about it: for instance, if you had $(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (1,2)$  you can first union them over all possible $i$, $(1,j), (2,j)$ and then union over all possible $j=1,2$ to get the whole set. Its exactly same thing

---

(d) When $X=x_i$, $Y$ can be any possible value, right? so we need to add probabilities when $Y=y_j$ takes a specific value over all possible $y_j$.
$$
P(X=x_i)= \sum_{y_j} P(X=x_i,Y)=\sum_{j} P(X=x_i,Y=y_j)
$$

(e) Now you can write

$$
E[X+Y]= \sum_i \sum_j (x_i+y_j)P(X=x_i,Y=y_j) = \sum_i x_i \sum_j P(X=x_i,Y=y_j) + \sum_j y_j \sum_i P(X=x_i,Y=y_j)
$$

can you apply part (d)?

Comment: thanks a lot :), let me check it, If i have some troubles can I ask you for help?

Comment: Sure, please do

Comment: well the first thing comes up, in the part c), Can I only show it like that saying that since the set $A_k$ is a partition we have (and the three sums) and then I conclude with the result?

Comment: ok :), the only thing I don't understand is the second sum :)

Comment: the one you do it over all i,j :)

Comment: I edited the answer - hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok let me check it :)